# ASP.NET MVC project kicks user out while using cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I am making an ASP.NET MVC web application using cookies. I have a login screen where I take username and password and there is a checkbox that remembers the user. If the user didn't check the checkbox, they should be forgotten upon closing the website. I can partially do this with the codes given below.

//A part of my AccessController/Login

```
if (loginViewModel.KeepLoggedIn) 
{
  authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
  {
    (IsPersistent = true), (ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30));
  }
} 
else 
{
  authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
  {
    (IsPersistent = true), (ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30));
  }
}
```

//Part of Program.cs where I create my cookie

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(option =>
    {
        option.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
        option.SlidingExpiration = true; // Renew the cookie on each request
        option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // Remember me for 30 days
    });
```

With this when the user exits the website they will be forgotten in 30 seconds. However if the user stays idle in the website for more than 30 seconds, their next action will take them to the login screen. How do I fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: IsPersistent = false and do not touch the expiration date at all

Comment: Thank you for your time, however when I do these changes the user is being kept as if they checked the remember me checkbox. Now they can exit the application and and re-enter it without seeing the login screen as if they were remembered.

Comment: I can provide additional code if needed.

Comment: Close the browser and reload your page. Not the current tab only. The browser.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you so much. I think it was due to cookies not being deleted properly? Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: This is how modern browsers work, they keep cookies for pages even though tabs are closed. Cookies are removed only when the whole browser is closed. This is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was changing IsPersistent to false and delete the ExpireUtc on the else statement. Afterwards, closing the whole browser -not just the tab your project is on- fixed the issue. Thanks to Wiktor Zychla.